# find set of points for lots of triangulations

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation

I should find a set of $n$ points $Q$ in a plane, so that $t(Q)$ (the number of possible triangulations) the following equation holds:

$$t(Q) \ge 2^{n-2\sqrt{n}}$$

---

I solved the problem using the vertex points of a convex polygon. Wikipedia says, that $t(Q) = C_{n-2}$ and by induction I can show, that $C_{n-2} \ge  2^{n-2\sqrt{n}}$.

I think, that this approach is way to complex. There must be a better solution, because $C_{n-2} \gg  2^{n-2\sqrt{n}}$ for big $n$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How complex is too complex?

The central binomial coefficient $\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}$ is bigger than $\displaystyle \frac{4^n}{2n+1}$, so

$\displaystyle t(Q) = C_{n-2} = \frac{1}{n-1} \binom{2(n-2)}{n-2} \geq \frac{1}{n-1} \frac{4^{n-2}}{2n - 3} = \frac{2^{n+2\sqrt{n} - 4}}{(n-1)(2n-3)} 2^{n-2\sqrt{n}}$

Since $2^{n+2\sqrt{n} - 4} \geq (n-1)(2n-3)$ for $n > 3$, and $C_{3-2} = 1 > 2^{3 - 2\sqrt{3}}$ we have $t(Q) \geq 2^{n-2\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Sorry, I meant, I want to use a different set than a convex polygon. Using convex polygons, I would have to proof the equation $t(Q)=C_{n-2}$ first. There mist be a simpler set, in which the inequality is much stricter. Otherwise the teachers would have said: show that $t(Q)=C_{n-2}$.